# How to Get the Current URL Inside @if Statement (Blade) in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel 4. I would like to access the current URL inside an `@if` condition in a view using the Laravel's Blade templating engine but I don't know how to do it.

I know that it can be done using something like `<?php echo URL::current(); ?>` but It's not possible inside an `@if` blade statement.

Any suggestions?

Comment: did any answer below help with your issue ?

Answer (score 435):

You can use: `Request::url()` to obtain the current URL, here is an example:

```
@if(Request::url() === 'your url here')
    // code
@endif
```

Laravel offers a method to find out, whether the URL matches a pattern or not

```
if (Request::is('admin/*'))
{
    // code
}
```

Check the related documentation to obtain different request information: http://laravel.com/docs/requests#request-information

Comment: <li{{ (Request::is('admin/dashboard') ? ' class="active"' : '') }}> i tried this, failed :x

Comment: In my case I was using a starting / for the URL, removing it would solve the issue

Comment: @Andreyco what if I need to put a banner on all the pages except the home page
try this not working
`@if(Request::url()!=='/')
    <div class="bannerImage">{{ HTML::image('images/fullimage3.jpg') }}</div>
@endif`

Comment: I use the next format for it: <li{!! (Request::url() == url('/')) ? ' class="active"' : '' !!}> , because the format with {{ some_code }} use string encoding.

Comment: `url()` [now returns a builder instance](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/helpers#method-url). must use `url()->current()`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII Could you provide Laravel version this change is related to? I will add note about this to answer. TY.

Comment: I'm not sure when it started, but the link I provided is for current 5.4

Comment: Although I upvoted this a long time ago, today I was having trouble with it on Laravel 5.7 and eventually got this to work instead: `@if (Request::path() != 'login')`. Notice the lack of slash before "login", too.

Comment: This leaves off the query string. Some answers below recommended `url()->full()`, which includes the query string.

Answer (score 114):

You can also use `Route::current()->getName()` to check your route name.

Example: routes.php

```
Route::get('test', ['as'=>'testing', function() {
    return View::make('test');
}]);
```

View:

```
@if(Route::current()->getName() == 'testing')
    Hello This is testing
@endif
```

Comment: FYI, `Route::is('testing')` is the same as `Route::current()->getName() == 'testing'`.

Comment: @Hkan No both are different, 
`Route::is('testing')` ->> testing it will not work
`Route::is('test')` ->> test it will work
`Route::current()->getName() == 'testing'`
alias and url are differents

Comment: @Naveen nope, `Route::is()` checks for the route name, not the path.

Comment: also shorthand `Route::currentRouteName()`

Comment: @Hkan Yeah, but that wouldn't work when working with parameters in your URL, for example, tokens ...

Comment: @Pathros you can use wildcards like `Route::is('foo.*)` or even `Route::is('foo*')`.

Answer (score 77):

Maybe you should try this:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('admin/dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}">Dashboard</li>
```

Answer (score 71):

To get `current url` in `blade` view you can use following,

```
<a href="{{url()->current()}}">Current Url</a>
```

So as you can compare using following code,

```
@if (url()->current() == 'you url')
    //stuff you want to perform
@endif
```

Comment: If you need to get the query string in the blade as well then you can use `request()->getQueryString()` which is very helpful in conjunction with `url()->current()` as that leaves off the query string.

Comment: ``` @if(url()->current() == '/admin/search-result' ``` I used this code but it doesn't work?

Comment: @MahdiSafari in that case just write `@if(Request::is('admin/search-result'))`

Comment: This worked very nicely. Thanks

Answer (score 55):

I'd do it this way:

```
@if (Request::path() == '/view')
    // code
@endif
```

where '/view' is view name in routes.php.

Comment: How to tell if the current dir is home? I mean, public/. Ahh, i got it, i just type `=='public'`

Comment: If home dir is '/' in route.php, you just write `== '/')`

Comment: How would you make it work with the parameters as well? Not only the route name.

Comment: You can concatenate parameters in many ways after route name, depending on how you configured your routes.

Comment: I do it like this: `Request::url()` - than you get the complete URL

Answer (score 29):

This is helped to me for bootstrap active nav class in **Laravel 5.2**:

```
<li class="{{ Request::path() == '/' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
<li class="{{ Request::path() == 'about' ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="/about">About</a></li>
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew the code but Google got me here in 5 seconds haha.

Comment: Also this same working with laravel 4.2 and it's working good. Thank you

Comment: Also working on Laravel 5.6, thanks... this just saved me from making navs for each view :D

Answer (score 20):

A little old but this works in L5:

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('mycategory/', '*') ? 'active' : ''}}">
```

This captures both /mycategory and /mycategory/slug

Comment: I'm using `{{ Request::is('clientes/*') ? 'active' : ''}}`

Answer (score 18):

***Laravel 5.4***

Global functions

```
@if (request()->is('/'))
    <p>Is homepage</p>
@endif
```

Comment: This does not always work if you're dealing with query string like so

domain.com/?page_id=1, domain.com/?page_id=2, as those URLs also equal as "/"

Comment: I used `request()->routeIs('...')`

Answer (score 18):

You will get the `url` by using the below code.

For Example your URL like `https//www.example.com/testurl?test`

```
echo url()->current();
Result : https//www.example.com/testurl

echo url()->full();
Result: https//www.example.com/testurl?test
```

Answer (score 17):

You can use this code to get current URL:

```
echo url()->current();

echo url()->full();
```

I get this from Laravel documents.

Answer (score 15):

I personally wouldn't try grabbing it inside of the view.  I'm not amazing at Laravel, but I would imagine you'd need to send your route to a controller, and then within the controller, pass the variable (via an array) into your view, using something like `$url = Request::url();`.

One way of doing it anyway.

EDIT: Actually look at the method above, probably a better way.

Answer (score 14):

For me this works best:

```
class="{{url()->current() == route('dashboard') ? 'bg-gray-900 text-white' : 'text-gray-300'}}"
```

Answer (score 12):

A simple navbar with bootstrap can be done as:

```
    <li class="{{ Request::is('user/profile')? 'active': '' }}">
        <a href="{{ url('user/profile') }}">Profile </a>
    </li>
```

Answer (score 10):

The simplest way is

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('contacts/*') ? 'active' : '' }}">Dashboard</li>
```

This colud capture the contacts/, contacts/create, contacts/edit...

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way is to use: `Request::url();`

But here is a complex way:

```
URL::to('/').'/'.Route::getCurrentRoute()->getPath();
```

Answer (score 9):

There are two ways to do that:

```
<li{!!(Request::is('your_url')) ? ' class="active"' : '' !!}>
```

or

```
<li @if(Request::is('your_url'))class="active"@endif>
```

Answer (score 9):

You should try this:

```
<b class="{{ Request::is('admin/login') ? 'active' : '' }}">Login Account Details</b>
```

Answer (score 8):

For named routes, I use:

```
@if(url()->current() == route('routeName')) class="current" @endif
```

Answer (score 7):

Set this code to applied automatically for each `<li>` + you need to using `HTMLBuilder` library in your Laravel project

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.list-group a[href="/{{Request::path()}}"]').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 7):

```
class="nav-link {{ \Route::current()->getName() == 'panel' ? 'active' : ''}}"
```

Answer (score 7):

In Blade file

```
@if (Request::is('companies'))
   Companies name 
@endif
```

Answer (score 7):

### 1. Check if URL = X

Simply - you need to check if URL is exactly like X and then you show something. In Controller:

```php
if (request()->is('companies')) {
  // show companies menu or something
}
```

In Blade file - almost identical:

```php
@if (request()->is('companies'))
  Companies menu
@endif
```

### 2. Check if URL contains X

A little more complicated example - method Request::is() allows a pattern parameter, like this:

```php
if (request()->is('companies/*')) {
  // will match URL /companies/999 or /companies/create
}
```

### 3. Check route by its name

As you probably know, every route can be assigned to a name, in `routes/web.php` file it looks something like this:

```php
Route::get('/companies', function () {
  return view('companies');
})->name('comp');
```

So how can you check if current route is 'comp'? Relatively easy:

```
if (\Route::current()->getName() == 'comp') {
  // We are on a correct route!
}
```

### 4. Check by routes names

If you are using routes by names, you can check if request matches routes name.

```php
if (request()->routeIs('companies.*')) {
  // will match routes which name starts with companies.
}
```

Or

```php
request()->route()->named('profile')
```

Will match route named profile. So these are four ways to check current URL or route.

[source](https://laraveldaily.com/post/how-to-check-current-url-or-route)

Comment: The question is about Laravel 4, and this is based on a tutorial for Laravel 9. `Request::is('companies')` is how it's done in Laravel 4.

Answer (score 6):

instead of using the **URL::path()** to check your current path location, you may want to consider the **Route::currentRouteName()** so just in case you update your path, you don't need to explore all your pages to update the path name again.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to write if and else in Laravel using path

```
 <p class="@if(Request::is('path/anotherPath/*')) className @else anotherClassName @endif" >
 </p>
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
@if(collect(explode('/',\Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()->url()))->last() === 'yourURL')
    <li class="pull-right"><a class="intermitente"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-alert"></i></a></li>
@endif
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation would greatly improve its long-term value](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/206345) by showing _why_ this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 2):

For Laravel 5.5 +

```
<a class="{{ Request::segment(1) == 'activities'  ? 'is-active' : ''}}" href="#">
                              <span class="icon">
                                <i class="fas fa-list-ol"></i>
                              </span>
                            Activities
                        </a>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@if(request()->path()=='/path/another_path/*')
@endif
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

There are many way to achieve, one from them I use always

```
 Request::url()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```html
<li class="{{ Request::is('Dashboard') ? 'active' : '' }}">
    <a href="{{ url('/Dashboard') }}">
 <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this  way :

```
<a href="{{ URL::to('/registration') }}">registration </a>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to your answer