# laravel 5 request::is() not working for active menu

Tags: laravel, laravel-request

I am new in Laravel, I'm trying to give active class to menu links if current url matches the menu link url,

```
<li @if (Request::is('student/lecture') || Request::is('admin/lecture/*')) class="active" @endif >
    <a href="{{ url('student/lecture') }}"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Lectures </a>
</li>
```

Its working for `student/lecture`  or `student/lecture/*`  , but its not wokring for `student/lecture/13?id=30` ( without sending id in get it work, but its not working when id is passed).

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591181/how-to-get-the-current-url-inside-if-statement-blade-in-laravel-4 will give you your answer.

Comment: `Request::is` doesn't match GET parameters. Only route itself.

Comment: thank you for help @MarkDavidson i found a work around in your provided link , just added `Route::current()->getName() == 'student.lecture.show'`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<li{!! (Request::is('student/lecture') || Request::is('admin/lecture/*') ? ' class="active"' : '') !!}>
    <a href="{{ url('student/lecture') }}"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i>Lectures </a>
</li>
```

Comment: tried still not working , i think its as @max.lanin said , Request::is doesn't match GET parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this one:

```
Request::is('user-wallet*')
```

Instead of this one:

```
Request::is('user-wallet/*')
```

The slash before the astrix will make the difference.