# Can i use the request path URI inside my blade template laravel 5?

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-blade

Quick question all,

Wondering if/how I can use the request path in my blade template. Currently using Laravel 5.2.

Ideally for alot of my forms they would just be submitting back to themselves. So wondering if there was an easy way to just put Request::path() in my form action.

I know i could just leave it blank but rather not leave it up to the browser to fill my action...

Thanks

Citti

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current URL inside @if statement (blade) in Laravel 4?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591181/how-to-get-the-current-url-inside-if-statement-blade-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `request()` helper. It returns an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` when called without parameters.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-request

```
{{ request()->path() }}
```

Comment: aww exactly what I was looking for. Thank you sir!