# Displaying content by view

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm new on Laravel and Blade. I've two different contents, one for Home, and second for any view, excluding home.

I've this code but nothing happens:

```
@if(view('home')) // Display content if is home, display 'foo'
    @include('partials/foo')
@else
    @include('partials/bar') // Okay, not in home, display 'bar'
@endif;
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: did my answer give you what you needed? If so, please mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved using this [How to get the current URL inside @if statement (blade) in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591181/how-to-get-the-current-url-inside-if-statement-blade-in-laravel-4)

```
@if(Request::is('/')) // Homepage
    'foo'
@else // All pages
    'bar'
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Route class in blade to get the method and decide based on method

```
@if(\Route::getCurrentRoute()->getActionMethod()  == 'index')
    @include('partials/foo')
@else
   @include('partials/bar') // Okay, not in home, display 'bar'
@endif;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would use a controller. The flow is as follows:

- your routes.web file has a route, such as `/home`
- this points to a public method on a controller, such as HomeController@index()
- The controller does any queries and calculations and then returns a view with needed data

In routes.web:

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');
```

In HomeController class:

```
public function index()
{
    $variable = ModelName::where('field', 'value')->first();

    return view('home')->with('variable', $variable);
}
```

This allows you to not have to check the view in blade because you are specifically sending it there.

Remove the variable stuff if you don't need it.