# Laravel - Different link navigation, same navbar

Tags: php, laravel, navbar

Am using same navbar for shop products and shop product. @if statement isn't working. Here is navbar:

```
<ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
      <li class="nav-item">

        @if (\Request::path('/shop'))
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Shop</a>
        @elseif (\Request::path('/product'))
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/shop">Shop</a>             
        @endif

      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#contact">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is routes:

```
Route::view('/product', 'shop.product');
Route::get('/shop', 'ShopController@index')->name('shop.index');
```

Comment: Looks like a dupe question.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591181/how-to-get-the-current-url-inside-if-statement-blade-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `request()->is()` function of request. as below:

```
@if (request()->is('shop'))
    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="#page-top">Shop</a>
@elseif (request()->is('product'))
    <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="/shop">Shop</a>             
@endif
```

Comment: Thanks Imran, followed the dupe question link but code still didnt work. Made a controller to bring in the request function (not sure whether was suppose to or not), then tried your request()->is() function code and it works...Cheers