# Current URL is not printing in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I need to print current URL. I am using below code

```
<a href="{! $request->url() !}">URL</a>
```

But it is not working.

Comment: You can use either `Request::url()` or `Request::fullUrl()` methods to get the current URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Get the Current URL Inside @if Statement (Blade) in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591181/how-to-get-the-current-url-inside-if-statement-blade-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I do it.

```
{{url()->current()}}
```