# How to get current route in laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I want to check if the current route isn't equal to a specific route in laravel view. How can I do that in Blade ?

my attempt:

```
 @if(Route::current() != Route('places.show'))
     <td><a href="/admin/places/display/{{$order->place->id}}">{{ $order->place->name }}</a></td>
 @endif
```

Comment: You can get the current url in blade as
url()->current() and then you can compare it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Get the Current URL Inside @if Statement (Blade) in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591181/how-to-get-the-current-url-inside-if-statement-blade-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Laravel Routes has method to get it.

To get current route name:

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::currentRouteName();
```

To check the current route is a matching route:

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::is('routename');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call the currentRouteName on the route class.

```
Route::currentRouteName();
```

Don't forget to use the class:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
```

To Check the current route:

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::is('routename');
```