# Laravel blade @if statement conditional to check route names

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

Is there a way to check the current page's route name with blade? I have a blade layout template that needs to change it's `<body>` attribute by the current uri. Note that I need to do this through blade, not js.

Here is an example snippet that illustrates what I want to do:

```
@if (URL::current() == {{ route('admin.index') }}) //not valid syntax
    <body class="dashboard" id="top">
@else 
    <body class="not-dashboard" id="not-top">
@endif
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Get the Current URL Inside @if Statement (Blade) in Laravel 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591181/how-to-get-the-current-url-inside-if-statement-blade-in-laravel-4)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can try `routeIs()` helper

```php
@if (request()->routeIs('admin.index'))
<body class="dashboard" id="top">
@else
<body class="not-dashboard" id="not-top">
@endif
```

---

and you code have syntax error which fix is

```php
@if (URL::current() == route('admin.index')) // remove those curly braces  
    <body class="dashboard" id="top">
@else 
    <body class="not-dashboard" id="not-top">
@endif
```